# How to arrange a Makefile to compile a kernel module with multiple .c files?

Tags: linux, makefile, module, kernel

How to arrange a Makefile to compile a kernel module with multiple .c files?

Here is my current Makefile. It was auto generated by [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)

```
TARGET = nlb-driver
OBJS = nlb-driver.o
MDIR = drivers/misc

EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/kernel/$(MDIR)

obj-m += $(TARGET).o

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)

ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4.,$(CURRENT)))
install:
    su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).o $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"
else
install:
    su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).ko $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"
endif

clean:
    -rm -f *.o *.ko .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

-include $(KDIR)/Rules.make
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the project consists of 6 files:

- `monter_main.c`, `monter_main.h`
- `monter_cdev.c`, `monter_cdev.h`
- `monter_pci.c`, `monter_pci.h`

`monter_main.c` is the main file of my module.

Remember that you shouldn't have a file with the same name as the module you're trying to build (e.g. `monter.c` and `monter.ko`) unless you've got all code in that one file.

Here are my Makefiles:

- **Makefile**

  ```
  KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

  default:
      $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

  install:
      $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install

  clean:
      $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean
  ```
- **Kbuild**

  ```
  obj-m := monter.o
  monter-objs := monter_main.o monter_cdev.o monter_pci.o
  ```

Comment: Why have two separate files `Makefile` and `Kbuild`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功 It is possible to do it in one file, but I was happy with this solution - I only had go modify Kbuild during development.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you could use `monter-objs := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(shell echo *.c))` so it creates a `.o` file corresponding to each `.c` one.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume that just listing more object files in the second line would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The dependencies for $(TARGET).o can be multiple object files, one for each source file in your driver. Many other drivers use the += operator after the initial declaration of OBJS. For example,

```
OBJS = nlb-driver.o
OBJS += file1.o
OBJS += file2.o
...
```

The target rule would then expand to be

```
$(TARGET).o: nlb-driver.o file1.o file2.o
    $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

This is nice if there are more source files than comfortably fit on a line. But if there are only a small number of files, you can also define all the objects on a single line

```
OBJS = nlb-driver.o file1.o file2.o
```